# Android with Firebase : Trying to implement RecycleView with CardView but can't retrieve RecycleView item position?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner, try to make a RecycleView layout with some information retrieve from Firebase database (in `MemberFragment.java`). In my code RecycleView layout with retrieve information from fire base database is worked but I can't retrieve item list position and can't be used for different massage display with different item list selected / clicked by user can any one help me how can I do it.
my code is:-

```
package np.com.rotaractnepalapp;


import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import np.com.rotaractnepalapp.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import np.com.rotaractnepalapp.Model.Member;
import np.com.rotaractnepalapp.ViewHolder.MemberViewHolder;

public class MemberFragment extends Fragment {

    View memFragment;
    RecyclerView listofMembers;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager memLayoutManger;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Member, MemberViewHolder> memAdapter;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference members;

    public static MemberFragment newInstance(){
        MemberFragment memberFragment = new MemberFragment();
        return memberFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        members = database.getReference("ClubKNE");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        memFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_member,container,false);

        TextView title = (TextView) memFragment.findViewById(R.id.txtClubNameTitle);
        title.setText("RAC Kathmandu North-East");

        listofMembers = (RecyclerView) memFragment.findViewById(R.id.memLists);
        listofMembers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        memLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
        listofMembers.setLayoutManager(memLayoutManger);

        loadMember();

        return memFragment;
    }

    private void loadMember() {
        memAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Member, MemberViewHolder>(
                Member.class,
                R.layout.mem_layout,
                MemberViewHolder.class,
                members
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MemberViewHolder viewHolder, Member model, int position) {
                viewHolder.memDesignation.setText(model.getMemDesignation());
                viewHolder.memName.setText(model.getMemName());
                viewHolder.memProfession.setText(model.getMemProfession());
                viewHolder.memEmail.setText(model.getMemEmail());
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(model.getMemImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.memImage);
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
                        view = factory.inflate(R.layout.member_info_layout, null);
                        alertDialog.setView(view);
                        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        alertDialog.show();

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        memAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listofMembers.setAdapter(memAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of an item, there are two solutions. One would be:

```
Member member = listMemenbers.get(position);
```

If you are using a list of `Member` objects. And second:

```
Member member = memAdapter.getItem(position);
```

In which case you are getting the position of the item directly from the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use position variable i.e int position it will show  the position of card or any other other value